# AJAX requests to fetch data from private API

Tags: ajax, api, rest, restful-authentication

I have a few projects (Chrome App, webOS app, Chromecast receiver) that all use a private API to fetch data from my database.

All requests are done via Post and the post data is sanitised on the API server (using CodeIgniter).

I have a few questions :

1) is this secure?

2) if not, how can I secure it?

3) if I wanted to use the API in an Android app, should I be looking at oauth (or another method of authentication) or are simple HTTP requests OK?

Remember, all these calls are to fetch data currently. No data is being inserted/updated.

Comment: This is too broad a question to answer. Security has many aspects that you would need to address.  How secure is the transport layer?  How secure is your authentication model?  How secure is your authorization model?  What potential attack vectors does your app have that need to be mitigated (i.e. XSRF, XSS, etc.)? What sort of data is being transported (do your API's just serve up publicly available data, or is there PII being transported)? My general thought is that if you don't know if your application is secure, then it probably is not.

Comment: So what kind of things can I do to make sure my AJAX requests are secure?

Answer (score 0):

Security isn't a binary yes/no.

I would suggest that you should assume that someone can/could see the code you are using and so the security should not rely on the API endpoint or syntax being secret/private.

The security should instead rely on other factors, such as using TLS (https) requests and using a strong password/API "key".

Comment: How do I use an API key with AJAX? The code is client side so they can easily see any key I send with the request? And they aren't the kind of apps I can easily have the user insert an API key,as they need to be simple to use apps.

Comment: So what is it that you mean by "secure"? Secure from what, exactly?

Comment: Secure from any wrong doing. If the AJAX requests are purely fetching data, is it 100% secure?

Comment: If you're not using https (TLS) then it's not free from eavesdropping or man-in-the-middle insertion of attack code into the client. If the API won't allow modification, then it should be free from unwanted modifications at the server. It is susceptible to denial of service (flooding) but then most any endpoint is.